# Datatables - integrating the editor into my existing tables

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I have some tables setup using the Datatables plug-in (http://www.datatables.net) and the Datatables Editor (http://editor.datatables.net).

I am trying to integrate the editor into my existing tables but get undefinded in all edit fields (in the pop up).

The only difference I can see between what I have and the generator download is the aoColumns setting.

This is what I currently have:

```
"aoColumns": [
{  "sTitle": "id" },
{  "sTitle": "Name" },
{  "sTitle": "Surname" },
{  "sTitle": "Email" }
```

but the editor code has:

```
"aoColumns": [
{  "mDataProp": "id" },
{  "mDataProp": "Name" },
{  "mDataProp": "Surname" },
{  "mDataProp": "Email" }
```

when I change "sTitle" to "mDataProp" my table no longer loads.

I'm clearly going the wrong way about this... Any direction on this would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is my full code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fnShowHide( iCol ){
        /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
        var oTable = jQuery('#example').dataTable();

        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
    }

    (function($){

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var aDataSet = [
            var aDataSet = [
['805',
'Emelia',
'Smith',
'emelia_s@yahoo.com'
],
['804',
'david',
'Davies',
'ddavies@yahoo.co.uk'
],      
    ]; 
                    var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
                        "ajaxUrl": "php/table.wp_newsletter.php",
                        "domTable": "#example",
                        "fields": [
                {
                    "label": "First Name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Last Name",
                    "name": "surname",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Email Address",
                    "name": "email",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ]
                    } );
                    var oTable;             
                    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                        "sDom": '<"postbox full"<W>><"clear"><"postbox full"<C><T>><"clear"><"postbox full"<lfr>><"clear"><"postbox full"<t>>ip',
                        "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
                            "aiExclude": [ 0,1,2,3,6,7,9 ],
                        },
                        "iDisplayLength": 50,
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "bSortClasses": false,
                        "aaData": aDataSet,
                        "oLanguage": {
                            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
                        },
                        "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "sRowSelect": "multi",
                        "aButtons": [
                            { "sExtends": "editor_create", "editor": editor },
                            { "sExtends": "editor_edit",   "editor": editor },
                            { "sExtends": "editor_remove", "editor": editor }
                        ]
                        },
                        "aoColumns": [
                            { "sTitle": "id" },
                            { "sTitle": "Name" },
                            { "sTitle": "Surname" },
                            { "sTitle": "Email" },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Admin",
                                "sClass": "center",
                                "sDefaultContent": '<a href="" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
                            }
                        ],
                    } );

                    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 7, false );
                    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 8, false );
                    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 9, false );

                    // New record
                    $('a.editor_create').on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        editor.create(
                            'Create new record',
                            { "label": "Add", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } }
                        );
                    } );

                    // Edit record
                    $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        editor.edit(
                            $(this).parents('tr')[0],
                            'Edit record',
                            { "label": "Update", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } }
                        );
                    } );

                    // Delete a record (without asking a user for confirmation)
                    $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        editor.remove( $(this).parents('tr')[0], '123', false, false );
                        editor.submit();
                    } );

                    var asInitVals = new Array();

                    $("#filter input").keyup( function () {
                        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
                        oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("#filter input").index(this)+1 );
                        //console.log($("#filter input").index(this)+1);
                    } );
                    /*
                     * Support functions to provide a little bit of 'user friendlyness' to the textboxes in 
                     * the footer
                     */
                    $("#filter input").each( function (i) {
                        asInitVals[i] = this.value;
                    } );

                    $("#filter input").focus( function () {
                        if ( this.className == "search_init" )
                        {
                            this.className = "";
                            this.value = "";
                        }
                    } );

                    $("#filter input").blur( function (i) {
                        if ( this.value == "" )
                        {
                            this.className = "search_init";
                            this.value = asInitVals[$("#filter input").index(this)];
                        }
                    } );

    } );

    }(jQuery));


        </script>
```

Comment: Could you be so kind, and add the whole Initialization code to the question? And also can you add this function `$.fn.dataTable.Editor()` to the question so we can inspect it for any possible errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
    "aoColumns": [
   {  "mDataProp": "id" },
   {  "mDataProp": "Name" },
   {  "mDataProp": "Surname" },
   {  "mDataProp": "Email" }
```

to

```
"aoColumns": [
{  "sTitle": "id" },
{  "mDataProp": "name", "sTitle": "Name" },
{  "mDataProp": "surname", "sTitle": "Surname" },
{  "mDataProp": "email", "sTitle": "Email" }
```

I know from experience that datatables/jvascript is case sensitive so that might have been the issue with the `mDataProp`. If that's not it , we can go search deeper :D

UPDATE:

Change this:

```
"fields": [
            {
                "label": "First Name",
                "name": "name",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "Last Name",
                "name": "surname",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "Email Address",
                "name": "email",
                "type": "text"
            }
```

To:

```
"fields": [
            {
                "label": "ID",
                "name": "id",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "First Name",
                "name": "name",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "Last Name",
                "name": "surname",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "Email Address",
                "name": "email",
                "type": "text"
            }
```

And then update this:

```
"aoColumns": [
{  "mDataProp": "id", "sTitle": "id" },
{  "mDataProp": "name", "sTitle": "Name" },
{  "mDataProp": "surname", "sTitle": "Surname" },
{  "mDataProp": "email", "sTitle": "Email" }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I got this error in an alert: `DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter 'name' from the data source for row 0`

Comment: Thanks @Iro . I got the same error message and tables are empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: @cybercampbell can you give me an example row from the aoData? I think it just doesn't like the structure or something.

Comment: Hi @Iro, dataset example added above

Comment: @cybercampbell usually that error means that that JSON data is not formatted correctly, but looking at yours it seems fine... I'm going to try to replicate this into jsfiddle to see if some trail and error will help.